# UTF8-Reporte de Excel PHP

Tags: php, excel, utf-8

Tengo el problema que no me reconoce los caracteres especiales, he intentado con lo siguiente pero no se muestra correctamente:

Mi header

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Columna en la cual quiero que me muestre asentos, caracteres raros etc.

```
->setCellValue('G' .$i, utf8_encode($row['objetivo']));
```

Tambien intenté ponerlo sin utf8

```
->setCellValue('G' .$i, $row['objetivo']);
```

Header Finales

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Evaluaciones-'.date('Y-m-
d').'.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

Comment: No se mucho de php, pero ya intentaste un utf8_decode() ?

Comment: Si. Lo puse así ->setCellValue('G' .$i, utf8_decode($row['objetivo'])); y sin resultados aun. Gracias

Comment: Y si intentas colocar en el charset del header iso-8859-1, cuando yo voy a exportar una tabla de mi db a excel le digo que ese sea el charset y me saca todo perfecto siempre y cuando los datos estén ingresados correctamente con sus caracteres especiales, es decir que en los registros no se vean alterados

Comment: Los registros en la DB estan alterados; como los ingreso correctamente? En el head ya tengo <meta charset="utf-8"> pero es código embebido con PHP tambien debo poner header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");?

Comment: Ya le puse header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"); cuando guardo los registros, pero aun asi no se guardan correctamente en la DB

Comment: Y si haces un encode o decode a cada valor que agregas a la base de datos antes de agregarlos? Pienso yo que si logras hacer que ingresen de manera correcta a la base lograrás hacer que impriman de la misma manera, pero como te digo no se mucho de backend

Comment: Solo una consulta, estas haciendo eso Con la libreria phptoExcel? miro que hablan de la base de datos y de text/html, estoy un tanto confundido

Comment: Con PHPExcel y de hecho haciendo utf8_encode ya funciona parcialmente

Answer (score 1):

Me gustaria ver un var_dump($resultadosdelaBd) de tu codigo, pero hice la prueba y no encuentro problemas con este ejemplo, te lo dejo completo para que lo pruebes, solo cambia los require_once de tu phpToExcel

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/phpModules/phpToExcel/PHPExcel.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/phpModules/phpToExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');    

$resultadoDB=[
    ["campo1"=>"texto con caracteres ##$%&/()","campo2"=>"texto normal"],
    ["campo1"=>"Campo con acentos ÄáéíóúÜ ","campo2"=>"xyz"],
];

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$hoja1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$hoja1->fromArray($resultadoDB, null, 'A1', true);
$hoja1->setTitle('Test');


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Elarchivo.xlsx');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Te funcionó el ejemplo?, saludos

Comment: Me funciono haciendo un utf8_encode a las ROWS

Comment: Bien, seguramente, el problema era entonces al traer los datos de la bd, y no de phpToExcel

Comment: Más bien de como se enviaban los datos a la BD

Comment: hahahahaha ya veo, me alegro que hayas resuelto tu problema